# Input a values at the same line in C++

Tags: c++

when i try to input tow values in c++ such as 2,2[as you see in the image]
it's looked like 
2
2
each of them in a new line
why he insert a new line between them?
How i can insert them at the same line like that ?
2 2

> int x,y; 
>   cin>>x>>y;

Comment: can you show the example of code?

Comment: int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;

Comment: it should work even if you write your values in the same line

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/  looke here in this link the input is 1 and 10 separate with a space i need to do like that

Comment: and how it is can be??

Comment: do you mean i let the user insert them like a string then i pars them into int when i want to use them?

Comment: `cin >> x >> y;` will input two values separated by white-space. It doesn't matter if they are on the same line separated by a single space, or 10 lines apart separated by any number of spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
```

And this should read in a line and separate it by spaces when you use standard input.

Comment: looke here in this link the input is 1 and 10 separate with a space i need to do like that

Comment: Yes. This is what this code does? Check it yourself. @ZaherHa https://onlinegdb.com/B1veOC1aZ

Comment: oh  brother i think you miss understand me i need them to be at the same line in the input not in the output i do not need to use cout i need  to use just cin

Comment: @ZaherHa Did you even try using the code? Maybe you should learn to actually run the example and input two numbers on the same line and see it works EXACTLY like you want it to?